# SSRS How to select a Facility in SSRS report and pass that selection to a website to get additional information

Tags: reporting-services

How to select a State(link) on SSRS report and pass that selection to a website(URL) and have it dynamically retrieve that State on that website. This will display the Facilities in that State information.

So I have searched high and low and I keep finding variations of this question but nothing exactly like this. Is it possible?

The expression is something like this:
="http://hcaxxxxxcare.com/locations/?state="& Fields!State.Value

Comment: Did you try putting that expression in the `Action` of the text box to `Go to URL`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already know what you need to do with link to add the state to it from the STATE field:

```
="http://hcaxxxxxcare.com/locations/?state=" & Fields!State.Value
```

To use it, you'd have an object (probably a table) where you display the state name as the expression.

[image]

Then add an **ACTION** to the text box to **Go to URL** with your expression:

```
="http://hcaxxxxxcare.com/locations/?state=" & Fields!State.Value
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing. However, it will only open the entire list of States .. it will not go to a specific state. So, I am selecting the Florida link on my report and it opens to the entire list of States not specifically to Florida.

Comment: Take a look at the URL with a specific state. Ex for florida what does the URL look like, are there any other parameters being passed?

Comment: If you select a state the URL looks like this:    
http://hcahealthcare.com/locations/?state=FL

Comment: Hmm - When I use `locations/?state=FL`, it seems to just get the Florida centers. Are you sure there isn't a space before the **=** ? That's the only way I could get ALL. Or are you using a funky browser?

Comment: I can get it to pull up Florida if I put   locations/?state=FL. However, I don't want to look at Florida every time. I want it to go to the state that I select in my report.

Comment: The state **should** change based on your STATE field in the expression. So when you click on a link and a window opens, the URL does have `?state=TN` (or whatever state) in your browser address bar but the web page brings up ALL locations?

Comment: Yes, ultimately that is how it should work. However, when I select TN on my report it opens up the URL but it doesn't pull up TN. It opens the page that contains all the states ... it doesn't automatically select TN as it should since I originally selected TN on my report.

Comment: Does the `/?state=TN` appear in the address window (without any spaces)?

Answer (score 0):

You were correct it was a silly space. I can't believe it but thank you!!